# What is a UFCL brand circuit?

Tags: electrical, gfci, safety

I'm shopping for a combination vent fan/light for a bathroom, and some of the ones I've found state this:

> UL Listed for use over bathtubs and
>   showers when connected to a GFCI
>   protected branch circuit. 7 1/8" high
>   housing, 4" round duct connector. Not
>   for use over cooking surfaces. U.L.
>   rated. If placed over bath or showers
>   must be installed on a UFCL brand
>   circuit.

What exactly is a "UFCL brand circuit"? I'm quite familiar with a GFCI protected circuit - is that just another term for the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it stands for **U**niform **F**ire **C**ode **L**isted and means that all components in the circuit have been tested to conform to the Uniform Fire Code, i.e. NFPA 1.  (I'm extrapolating from a UL or cULus listing meaning that a product has been tested to the appropriate UL standard.)  Since the National Electrical Code is part of the NFPA standards, that would imply that the circuit must meet requirements for a bathroom circuit, i.e. GFCI protection.

They would be called out separately in their literature because UL and the NFPA are separate, independent, organizations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this term is a result of a computer translation error. A quick Google search turns up several iterations of this which are essentially copies of each other, or copies from a really poor translation. One of the sites which I found, that described Nutone fan installation on a UFCL brand circuit, also said that a particular fan was "Rated 70 cubic little legs per few minutes". It also explained that a fan had a "Specially styled polymeric freakout blade" and "Includes junction parcel with regard to focused wiring".
It all points to simply another company that didn't think it was important to hire a native English speaker to translate. Too bad this copied even to Amazon.

Go with the GFCI protected branch wiring and you won't have to worry about how to "operate the humidity" in your "bath space".

PS, after reading the entire page, I think that "freakout" means "impeller".

Comment: The "freakout blade" obviously initiates the disco ball feature.

Answer (score 1):

Its gotta be a GFCI.  I can't find anything stating what this means.  The only reference I see are  other lights / fans that required that.